# How to extract random entries from multiple mysql tables directly from database?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to extract a maximum of 5 entries randomly from two tables combined directly from database.

kinda like this `SELECT RANDOM FROM table1,table2 LIMIT 0,5)`

I am aware that I can filter the result later on from PHP, but I want only 5 random rows from database.

These multiple tables might have different database structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered something like

```
(SELECT * from table1) union (select * from table2) order by rand() limit 0,5
```

Comment: Now that i think of it, i think you need to union all the entries in both tables and then use the order by rand() limit 5

Comment: no this didn't work, only random entries from table 1 are showing up

Comment: It is giving this error "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns". The structures are different

Comment: @Starx: Don't do `SELECT *`. Instead, select only the columns that you want in the result set: `SELECT field_1, field_2, ...`

Comment: Hmmmmm... that's a whole different thing. Have you considered implementing a UDF that 

1. selects a random value to pick the source table
2. selects a random row from that same table ?

Comment: Good point Daniel, assuming those rows from distinct tables have anything relevant in common. If that's the case, i agree.